# What happens to a Facebook account when it is reported as compromised?

Tags: facebook, account-management, passwords, hacked, password-recovery

According to Facebook,

> If you believe your account has been compromised by another person or a virus, please click the "My Account Is Compromised" button below. We'll help you log back into your account so that you can regain control.

**References:**

- http://www.facebook.com/hacked
- http://www.technobuzz.net/recovering-a-hacked-facebook-account/
- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10507004/repost-what-happens-to-a-facebook-account-when-it-is-reported-as-compromised

**Question:** When an account is reported as being compromised or hacked, what happens to the account? Is the account or any of its content deleted? I cannot seem to find much on what goes on past the "I'm sure I want to proceed with recovery and reporting this account as compromised." What happens next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok.

What happens?  Well, depending on the path you follow, different things.

For example, you can be asked to fill out a form that asks you questions regarding information relating to your account, as is described in [this article](http://fixexe.com/facebook-account-got-hacked-need-help/).  Then, as that article says, someone at Facebook reviews the information and checks it against what they already have.

Once you report the account as compromised, it is locked down.  Meaning only the people at Facebook can access it.  Then, you must provide enough information to prove it was yours.  Then, you get access to the account to fix/change back any information that was changed (like the email address the password would get sent to, etc.)

Comment: One of the concerns that was raised was in reaction to the fact that Facebook accounts reported as compromised are in fact locked down. This concern is surrounding whether or not Facebook would take actions on its own to delete the account or its data (which we're trying to avoid here). So long as we at least enter a manual review process, I'm fine with that. That article by the way references an outdated link that now points to Facebook's somewhat (albeit not altogether) helpful FAQ. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yeah, Facebook doesn't delete the account if it has been reported as compromised.  They will, at the very least, attempt to work to restore it to it's rightful owner... providing that the rightful owner is the one who reported it compromised, AND attempts to get it back.  I suppose if an account is reported as compromised, and nothing is done at that point by anyone... facebook might delete it at some point... but I doubt it would even be right away.